# Excel: How to create multiple if statements/checks in the same cell? To output a certain amount depending on what number is entered

Tags: excel

I am creating a spreadsheet for work, and the situation goes as follows:
A "Type" column, that specifies the type of job. This is expressed as a Type 1, Type 2, or Type 3. (1, 2, 3)
A "Price" column, that expresses the price of the work being done in the apartment building.

My question is, how can I code an if statement in the "Type" cell to send information to the "Price" cell, with the 'price cell' changing based on what number is put in the 'type cell'.

Here are the values for the types:
1- $1,975
2- $3,950
3- $6,875

Example code:

```
IF(TYPECELL=1, THEN PRICECELL='1975', IF TYPECELL=2, THEN PRICECELL=3950, etc..
```

Basically, having multiple if statements/checks to see if the user put in a 1,2, or 3 into the "Type" box, and having that subjective scenario output a certain amount into the price box depending on which "type" it is.

It does not matter to me if the code is put in the "Type" cell, to pull input from the type cell & send it to the price cell, or if the code is in the price cell, and pulls input from the type cell and posts into the price cell. I have noticed in this way, there is an issue with the cell trying to write over itself with a code present.

Sorry if that was hard to understand, I tried to explain it the best that I can. Thank you very much!

Comment: `=CHOOSE(A1,1975,3950,6875)` where `A1` is the cell in which the user puts the type.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe has several possible formula solutions.

- use a `Choose()` formula as suggested in the comment
- use the `IFS()` function `=IFS(A1=1,1975,A1=2,3950,A1=3,6875)`
- create a lookup table and use a lookup function like `Vlookup`

A lookup function will be more flexible if the parameters change and the values need to be adjusted. Then you only need to change the lookup table and not every formula.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you for this :)
It helped me out tremendously in making a simple spreadsheet for my job. I'm personally not any tech field there, I'm a standard mold remediator, but we were doing work for an apartment complex. We needed to keep track of the apt units that we were doing work on, so that way we could have an updated balance of the price of the job.

Comment: You can mark the answer as described in the [tour]. That's the best way to say thank you around here.